# How to add a title with greek letters to a Plotly graph with R?

Tags: r, plot, plotly, r-plotly, plotmath

```r
library(plotly)

f <- plot_ly(alpha = 0.5) %>% 
            add_histogram(x=rnorm(1000), 
                          name="Observed",
                          marker=list(color="darkolivegreen")
                         )
            )

f %>% layout(title=expression(theta==0.8%*%hat(theta)))
```

I have a **Plotly** histogram in R, and I want to add the following title to it. It doesn't have to be a title; just **a text saying that in the blank area** of the graph will do. Apparently **Plotly** doesn't accept `expression()` from `plotmath` so the code above fails. It's the **hat** part that makes me really wanna show it as a proper equation; would be so much clearer. Can anybody help me out here?

[image: equation]

---

I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436554/how-to-include-greek-letters-and-bold-characters-in-a-legend-using-plotly) as Plotly often borrows from **CSS** ([tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_greek.asp)). However, `add_text(x=10, y=10, text="<b>theta = 0.8*theta_hat</b>")` did generate a bold text, but `add_text(x=50, y=50, text="<p>&theta</p>"` or `add_text(x=50, y=50, text="<p>&theta;</p>"` does not generate greek letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Latex, as suggested at this [link](https://plotly.com/r/LaTeX/).

```
f <- plot_ly(alpha = 0.5) %>% 
            add_histogram(x=rnorm(1000), 
                          name="Observed",
                          marker=list(color="darkolivegreen")
                         )
   
f %>% layout(title=TeX("\\theta = 0.8 \\hat\\theta")) %>% 
      config(mathjax = 'cdn')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!  But somehow it returns `Error in TEX("\\theta = 0.8 \\hat\\theta") : could not find function "TEX"`

Comment: The function is `TeX` not `TEX`